# jquery plugin - chosen - multiple selection not listing in a row but a column

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I am trying to configure my ListBox to use the jquery plugin, chosen 1.4.

I get the values for the ListBox from the database and add each item to the ListBox in the code behind that works fine:

```
 //Populate the Recipient ListBox 
 DataTable tdtRecipients = new DataTable();
 tstrXmlTableData = m_pagingClient.GetRecipientList(m_strUserID);
 tdtRecipients = ParseXML(tstrXmlTableData);

  // string tstrRecipientLst = string.Empty;
  foreach (DataRow row in tdtRecipients.Rows)
  {
       lstBoxTo.Items.Add(row["Name"].ToString());                      
   }
```

The ListBox is styled to be long and to add vertical scroll bars if needed.  This is from the style sheet:

```
 #lstBoxTo
{
    width: 620px;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

The control is set within a panel:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="pnlTo" runat="server" CssClass="basicRow" ClientIDMode="Static">
     <asp:Label ID="lblTo" runat="server"  CssClass="labelText" Text="To: " 
                ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
     <asp:ListBox ID="lstBoxTo" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple"  
                ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:ListBox>
     </asp:Panel>
```

This is the javascript to use and configure the chosen plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function () {
      $("#lstBoxTo").data("placeholder", "Choose recipient(s)...").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

The ListBox is not displayed as wide as the stylesheet indicates but only as wide as the longest selection. The list is in a bulleted format and when you make multiple selections they are not in a row but a bulletted column.   The placeholder, 'Choose recipient(s)' is not shown but the default placeholder 'Select option'.

I would like the list box to display as on the web site, http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/, for Multiple Selections.  But I don't know what options to set or how to set them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.
**UPDATE**
After removing the ClientIDMode attribute and adding Height and width to the attributes, the ListBox displays correctly.
But in the demo, the ListBox should start with 'Choose Recipients' and the list shown below as you type.  The list is shown in the list box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...
I was missing the chosen style sheet.
Added:
    
To my Site.Master file and it works fine.

Hope this helps a newbie like me!!